# Probability and Expectation of rolling a 6 sided dice thrice

Tags: probability

I have a 6 sided fair dice.

Case 1 :- I have an option of throwing it twice to get a better number in my 2nd throw if I choose so. What should be the probability and expectation of this whole event?

Case 2:- I have an option of throwing it twice and thrice to get a better number in my 2nd and 3rd throw throw if I choose so. What should be the probability and expectation of this whole event?

How should I go about this? If this has already been answered, can someone point me to the right thread?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that Case 2 is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179534/the-expected-payoff-of-a-dice-game

Comment: Thanks, that's the 1 I needed