# The expected payoff of a dice game with n above 3 or in general any number

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value

For 3 cases, i particularly referred [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179534/the-expected-payoff-of-a-dice-game) and probably the best answer but when I take n=4 i.e. no of times dice can rolled, for I get expected off as 4.94 and for n=5, i get 5.12 that means for n=6, logically it means payoff i expect should be 6, and for any case above 6, for example here n=1000, the fair value which i should pay is 6 as that will be expected payoff. Am i right here, not missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected payoff will *never be exactly $6$*, but will approach it in the limit of infinite rolls.

For $4$ and $5$ dice the exact expected payoffs are $\frac{89}{18}$ and $\frac{277}{54}$ respectively. Since $\frac{277}{54}>5$, the expected payoff for $n$ dice from $n\ge6$, $E_n$, is computed from $E_{n-1}$ as
$$E_n=\frac66+\frac16E_{n-1}=1+\frac56E_{n-1}$$
So $E_6=\frac{1709}{324}$, for example. It is easy to show by induction that $E_n<6$ for all $n\ge1$, and that the sequence $\{E_n\}$ is strictly increasing, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}E_n=6$.

An intuitive reason for the expected payoff never being $6$ is that there is a nonzero probability of not getting a $6$ at all in any finite number of rolls, so sometimes you will have to settle for less than that.

Comment: Thankyou. Apparently i made a rookie mistake while saying the payoff would be 6. Another ques i should have added there, since the payoff is increasing concavely, for a case like n=1000, the player should continue to roll right till he get highest payoff, no matter probability of the same can be exhausting the total 1000 times still not getting 6, right?

Comment: @pkg7724 Yes, like that.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel No! You would not toss a 1000 times if your 999th toss is a 5. That’s what I explained in my answer. Because at 999th toss your expected payoff is just the same problem for n=2. So you’re happy to let go with a 5 as well. As 5 is larger than the expected pay off for n=2.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan My reply was only for the first $995$ tosses. For the last $5$ tosses, as you said, we have to tread a little more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Parcly’s answer

In the given strategy you might not even toss the coin n times and choose to settle with something less than 6. That is, say you’re in your $(n-2)^{th}$ toss according to the strategy you would quit if $(n-2)^{th}$ toss is a 5. Since you have only 2 more tosses left and your expected pay off given this situation is less than 5, so even though you had $n$ tosses to begin with you’re happy to let go off with a 5 now given there are only 2 more tosses left.

Hence your expected payoff would always  be less than 6 for a given finite number of tosses.