# Best strategy in dice game if you can keep more than one number

Tags: probability, dice

The question is similar to the original one, [The expected payoff of a dice game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179534/the-expected-payoff-of-a-dice-game/179554), but now we can keep $m>1$ numbers (dice).

Formally, let $X_1,...,X_n\sim \text{Unif }[0,1]$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables coming successively. We can keep at most $m$ numbers in hand where $1<m<n$. After seeing $X_i$, you may choose to stop, or you can discard one of the $m$ numbers and see the next random variable $X_{i+1}$.

What's the best strategy to maximize the sum of these $m$ values?

(For simplicity I take $X_i\sim \text{Unif }[0,1]$. Instead you may consider a dice if you want.)

Comment: As stated it looks like you discard any $x_i\lt \frac{1}{2}$ as long as you can.  If it is Bernoulli, discard $X_i=0$.

Comment: But in the original dice game (m=1), we discard the first dice if it is less than some threshold $\alpha_1$, and we discard the second dice if it is less than another threshold $\alpha_2$, where $\alpha_1>\alpha_2>E[X]$. So I'm guessing we also have similar thresholds here.

Comment: You need to clarify the game you are describing.